# How to Integrate Django's auth models with custom REACT front-end sign up

Tags: python, django

So, this question might be way too abstract but I feel the need to shoot the shot here. The Django I have been taught to use is quite out of convention where they do not use Django's default auth models/views. I will show you the example of my past SignUpView below:

```
from .models import Customer


class SignUpView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data = json.loads(request.body)

        try:
            validate_email(data['email'])
            if len(data['password']) < 6:
                return JsonResponse({'message': '6자리 이상 입력하세요'}, status=400)
            if not Customer.objects.filter(email = data['email']).exists():
                hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(data['password'].encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('utf-8')
                Customer.objects.create(
                        email = data['email'],
                        password = hashed_password,
                        username = data['username'],
                        phone = data['phone']
                )
                return JsonResponse({'message':'SUCCESS'}, status=200)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'message':'ALREADY_EXIST'}, status=400)
        except KeyError:
            return JsonResponse({'message':'INVALID_KEYS'}, status=400)
        except ValidationError:
            return JsonResponse({'message':'INVALID_EMAIL'}, status=400)
```

However, here comes the day I get requested to create SuperUser functionality and custom permission functionality, thus forcing me to give up on the way I was taught to make signup view. Below is what I have created today, following along some blog post

```
from django.shortcuts               import render
from django.contrib.auth.models     import User
from django.contrib.auth.models     import Permission
from django.contrib.auth.forms      import UserCreationForm
from django.views                   import View
from django.contrib.auth            import login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request,'accounts/index.html')

class SignUpView(View)
    def post(request):
        context = {}
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                login(request,user)
                return render(request,'accounts/index.html')
        context['form']=form
        return render(request,'registration/sign_up.html',context)
```

The code I just created won't work because I am not using the Django templates but rather my front-end teammates are creating forms, just like before. So, I will be receiving potential user's signup form using codes like so:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
email = data['email']
password = bcrypt.hashpw(data['password'].encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('utf-8')
username = data['username']
phone = data['phone']
```

Is there any way I can integrate Django's Auth functionality with custom sign up form like I just demonstrated? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to quite ask why you've been taught not to use Django's authentication system, and/or why you're rolling your own Bcrypt password hashing when [Django already does it, and likely more securely than you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#using-bcrypt-with-django), but...

If you already have

```
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
```

and

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
email = data['email']
password = 
username = data['username']
phone = data['phone']
```

then it's pretty straightforward to synthesize

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
form = UserCreationForm(data={
  'email': data['email'],
  'password': data['password'],
  'username': data['username'],
  'phone': data['phone'],
})
```

and get going with that, but I would recommend looking at e.g. [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to make API views like these much more straightforward to work with.

Comment: Does `form.is_valid()` work with your last code snippet?

Comment: Naturally. All you're doing is loading the user input not from regular POST form data, but the JSON blob.